# How to get visual studio 10 to open .mk files in the same instance?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, file, windows-7, associations

I've recently been migrated to windows 7, and upon re-installing VS2010, it seems to want to treat .mk files differently than it used to.

For whatever reason, it insists on opening a new instance of visual studio to edit these files.

It doesn't for .c, .h, etc.

I've tried using types, a freeware association manager, to change how it is associated. I've deleted the association, recreated, etc.  but it still seems to want to treat these separately.

Anybody know how to beat this thing into submission?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to replicate the ddeexec keys that you'll find under, say, `HKCR\VisualStudio.c.10.0\shell\Open`.  The VisualStudio.mk.10.0 progid is missing them.

Comment: You are a life saver.    Indeed, I used regedit.exe to export HKCR\VisualStudio.c.10.0\shell\Open , edited it with notepad to point to VisualStudio.mk and then imported it.
I had to do a little extra work to clean up some residual class types I had tried, but worked like a charm after that.